# SVG images are not displayed at ReactJS app

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have ReactJS app and I have an issue with my svg's. While I was on the development stage everything works fine, but now I am trying to prod it and my svg images are not shown. Here is the roots of my application:

```
.
├── src
│   ├── app.js (entrypoint)
│   ├── pages
│   │   └── service
│   │       └  backButton.jsx
│   └── images
│       └ back.svg
└── webpack.config.js
```

My **webpack.config.js**:

```
const webpack = require('webpack'); 
var path = require('path');
require('babel-polyfill');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
require('dotenv').config({path: './.env'});
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/app.js'],
  output:{
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public'),
        publicPath: '/public/',
        filename: "bundle.js" 
  },

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 5500,
    open: true
  },

  plugins: [
    new Dotenv(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": JSON.stringify(process.env)
    })
  ],
  
  module:{
    rules:[
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/, // Babel loader.
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
          loader: "babel-loader", 
          options:{
              presets:["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
            }
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.svg$/, 
          loader: 'raw-loader' 
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

And part of **backButton.jsx** which is trying to use svg:

```
...
return (
      <img src="../../src/images/back.svg"/>
  )
...
```

All the other svg images are not displyed too. I have no idea what to do with, I've tried some other loaders but the result was the same.

Comment: When creating a production build and deploying it, you cannot rely on referencing assets in src unless it is loaded by webpack too. If you’re using webpack 4, you need to [use file-loader](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) to help you with it. For webpack 5, [use the built-in assets module instead](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use svg directly from the assets folder in jsx. You have to import it from the assets folder

```
import yourSvg from 'your svg path';

...
return (
  <img src={yourSvg} />
)
...
```

you can also check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-glitter-dpox1?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: thanks a lot! Finally it works. But it is still a mistery for me why it was working under development runs